# Чем заменить онлайн базу Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Подскажите, чем можно заменить онлайн базу Firebase? 
Есть небольшой проект, который использует Firebase как базу с данными. В последнее время стала появляться ошибка:

```
Caused by com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded.
```

То есть доступная квота на чтение данных закончилась и приложение крэшится. А расширять лицензию не хочется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё зависит от того для чего на самом деле Вы используете FireBase.

Если просто "хранить данные", то можно посмотреть в сторону того же SQLite. Если же это какое-то централизованное хранилище, то придётся либо расширять лицензию, ибо брать сервер под другую СУБД (что также не бесплатно). В любом случае сетевые ресурсы так или иначе стоят денег.